# Get first few words of a String in dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart

How to get first few words (excerpts) from a long `String`. I have a big story type String and need to display the first 5-10 words on the screen and remaining to be displayed on the next screen. So is there any way to get so. I searched a lot but couldn't resolve the issue.
Eg: TO get the first letter we use

```
String sentence = "My single Sentence";
sentence[0] //M
```

In the same way, I need to get some words.
Eg:

```
String bigSentence ='''
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
''';
//code to get the excerpt()

//predicted output=> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text...
```

Comment: If you really wanted to have splitted words, you may use sublist. You may check my answer below

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [substring](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/String/substring.html) method on `String` like this..

```
String myString = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
String smallString = myString.substring(0,5); //<-- this string will be abcde
```

For a specific use case, lets say if you want maximum of 30 characters no matter the number of words in the resulting string, then you could write a function like this..

```
String smallSentence(String bigSentence){
  if(bigSentence.length > 30){
    return bigSentence.substring(0,30) + '...';
  }
  else{
    return bigSentence;
  }
}
```

If the requirement is to specifically get the first few words, lets say first 6 words no matter the resulting string's length, then you could write a function like below. We will also need to use [indexOf](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/String/indexOf.html) method on `String`.

```
String firstFewWords(String bigSentence){
  
  int startIndex = 0, indexOfSpace;
  
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    indexOfSpace = bigSentence.indexOf(' ', startIndex);
    if(indexOfSpace == -1){     //-1 is when character is not found
      return bigSentence;
    }
    startIndex = indexOfSpace + 1;
  }
  
  return bigSentence.substring(0, indexOfSpace) + '...';
}
```

***Additional Edit for creating `extension` -***

You can create an `extension` on `String` like so

```
extension PowerString on String {

  String smallSentence() {
    if (this.length > 30) {
      return this.substring(0, 30) + '...';
    } else {
      return this;
    }
  }

  String firstFewWords() {
    int startIndex = 0, indexOfSpace;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      indexOfSpace = this.indexOf(' ', startIndex);
      if (indexOfSpace == -1) {
        //-1 is when character is not found
        return this;
      }
      startIndex = indexOfSpace + 1;
    }

    return this.substring(0, indexOfSpace) + '...';
  }
}
```

And use it like this

```
  String bigText = 'very big text';
  
  print(bigText.smallSentence());
  print(bigText.firstFewWords());
```

Comment: i mean, good that it worked for OP, but technically this is not the correct answer to the question, since expected output for OPs example was "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text", not "Lorem".

Comment: I have same notion. Therefore I just added below new solution that is more relevant to the title

Comment: @scrimau, yes right. I have now edited the answer to include specific implementation.

Comment: the problem is: the first 30 characters are not necessarily the first 5 words of a string, and OPs question explicitly stated words not characters. OP maybe can work with a character limit or even wanted a function to split a string with a character limit, but the question asks explicitly for a word limit.

Comment: @scrimau , then again a limit on words won't ensure a limit on characters and vice versa. So it highly depends on the end goal one is trying to achieve. But yes, both cases could be possible. So I have edited the answer to include that case too.

Comment: How could you make a Extension on this function?

Comment: @JohanWalhout I have edited the answer to include how an `extension` on `String` can be made for this.

Answer (score 8):

## A. Easy Way

To Split String, we are required to have several steps :

1. Turn it to List
2. Make New Smaller List
3. Transform it back to String

### Step 1

To turn String into List, we can use this

```
String bigSentence = 'Lorem Ipsum is'
bigSentence.split(" ")
// ["Lorem", "Ipsum", "is"]
```

### Step 2

Make New Smaller List, for example get first two words,

we use [sublist](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/List/sublist.html)

```
List<String> splitted = ["Lorem", "Ipsum", "is"]
splitted.sublist(0, 2)
// ["Lorem", "Ipsum"]
```

### Step 3

Transform it back to String

```
List<String> smaller = ["Lorem", "Ipsum"]
smaller.join(" ")
// "Lorem Ipsum"
```

### Full Functional Code

at the end, we can simplify it to `single line of code`

```
String getFirstWords(String sentence, int wordCounts) {
  return sentence.split(" ").sublist(0, wordCounts).join(" ");
}

String bigSentence = '''
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
''';

main() {
  String result = getFirstWords(bigSentence, 2);
  print(result); // Lorem Ipsum


  String resultDots = getFirstWords(bigSentence, 2) + " ...";
  print(resultDots); // Lorem Ipsum ...


}
```

#### Alternatives

Actually, there is another options to achive New Smaller List as suggested in Step 2

Use `take`

```
List<String> splitted = ["Lorem", "Ipsum", "is"]
splitted.take(2)
// ["Lorem", "Ipsum"]
```

## B. Hard Way

As suggested by `scrimau`, the first method above may experience performance **hit** by its inefficiency splitting maybe thousands of words at first, in order to get several words.

I just learned that `Dart` has [Runes](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Runes-class.html), that may helps us in this case.

To iterate String, firstly we need to transform it into Runes. As stated here, Runes [has](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Runes/iterator.html) iterable

### We need to have several steps :

#### 1. Validate find Count

```
  if (findCount < 1) {
    return '';
  }
```

#### 2. Turn Separator and Sentence into Runes

```
  Runes spaceRunes = Runes(wordSeparator);
  Runes sentenceRunes = Runes(sentence);
```

#### 3. Prepare Final String

```
  String finalString = "";
```

#### 4. Iterate Runes

**The most important part is here**, for your case, we need to find Space ' '

So, later if we already found enough space, we just return the `Final String`

If we have not found enough space, iterate more and append then `Final String`

Also note here, we use [.single](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Iterable/single.html), so the word separator must be single character only.

```
  for (int letter in sentenceRunes) {
    // <------ SPACE Character IS FOUND----->
    if (letter == spaceRunes.single) {
      findCount -= 1;
      if (findCount < 1) {
        return finalString;
      }
    }
    // <------ NON-SPACE Character IS FOUND ----->
    finalString += String.fromCharCode(letter);
  }
```

### Full Functional Code

```
String bigSentence = '''
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
''';

String getFirstWordsFast(String sentence, String wordSeparator, int findCount) {
  if (findCount < 1) {
    return '';
  }

  Runes spaceRunes = Runes(wordSeparator);
  Runes sentenceRunes = Runes(sentence);
  String finalString = "";

  for (int letter in sentenceRunes) {
    if (letter == spaceRunes.single) {
      findCount -= 1;
      if (findCount < 1) {
        return finalString;
      }
    }
    finalString += String.fromCharCode(letter);
  }
  return finalString;
}

main() {
  String shorterString = getFirstWordsFast(bigSentence, " ", 5);
  print(shorterString); // Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
}
```

Comment: performance is bad for this for long strings though ... since `split` continues to split the string even after 2 matches... is there a more performant way?

Comment: Or extra easier way, bigSentence.split(" ").first;
&  bigSentence.split(" ").last;

Answer (score 6):

```
void main() {
  String bigSentence =
      "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book";
  
  /// if length of string is greater than 6 words then append dots
  bool appendDots = false;
  
  
  /// this will split string into words
  List<String> tempList = bigSentence.split(" ");

  int start = 0;
  int end = tempList.length;
  /// extract first 6 words
  if (end > 6) {
    end = 6;
    appendDots = true;
  }
  /// sublist of tempList
  final selectedWords = tempList.sublist(start, end);
  /// join the list with space
  String output = selectedWords.join(" ");

   if(appendDots){
     output += "....";
   }
  
  print(output);
}
```

**Edit : Another Solution**

```
Text('Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book',
   maxLines : 1,
   overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, 
),
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer ```.substring()``` method worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
  String sentence = "My single Sentence";
  print(sentence.split(" "));
```

Try using `split(" ")` and assign it to a variable and then you can get the first word.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer ```.substring()``` method worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
String sampleText = "Lorem ipsum";

sampleText.split(" ").elementAt(0) // Lorem
sampleText.split(" ").elementAt(1) // ipsum
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same task, made an extension that `truncate` whole words with required length and add to the end the suffix.

```
/// turuncate the [String] without cutting words. The length is calculated with the suffix.
extension Truncate on String {
  String truncate({required int max, String suffix = ''}) {
    return length < max
        ? this
        : '${substring(0, substring(0, max - suffix.length).lastIndexOf(" "))}$suffix';
  }
}
```

An example how to use

```
print('hello world two times!'.truncate(max: 15, suffix: '...'));
```

the result is `hello world...`